# I am getting lost inside my own code

Tags: c++, xcode

I have noticed I am getting lost more often than not when writing more than one screen of code. Most of my code is C++ which tends to be lengthy, and I am using a Mac with Xcode9.

I haven't found a solution like a minimap for Xcode (the ones I have found seem deprecated). I am using comments for almost everything but they tend to look similar so it doesn't seem to help much....

Does anyone have any suggestions? Good practices or anything?

Thanks

Comment: Don't write overly long functions (anywhere near a screenful is too long in almost all cases); put closely related things close together; put entirely unrelated things in separate files; name things thoughtfully and consistently; use the navigation tools that XCode already has.

Comment: I recommend "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin. It's most likely not a problem with your IDE, but the problem with your code.

Answer (score 5):

> I am using comments for almost everything

If comments just repeat what your code is doing anyway, skip them. Comments should supply *additional* information that is not obvious anyway. Example:

```
++i; // increment i
```

That's entirely useless...

```
// need to increment i BECAUSE otherwise...
// need to increment NOW, earlier/later causes this or that problem
++i;
```

In above cases, it might not be obvious *why* you increment at all or why it must be done exactly here and not at another location. So you explain.

A good hint for when you need a comment is if you get back to your code after a while (a few weeks or more) and discover that you do not understand your own code immediately, but have to think about what you did here...

Another way to get better readability is keeping indentation level low:

```
if(a)
{
    if(b)
    {
         if(c)
         {
         }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
else
{
}
```

often (but not always) can be transformed into:

```
if(!a)
{
}
else if(!b)
{
}
else if(!c)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Sometimes this can lead to code such as:

```
else if((x = f(y)) == z)
```

Admitted, not that nice to read either. I personally think it is worth the reduced indentation depth of the if-else chain, but in this case, you should make up your own mind...

If you functions get too large, you can break them into smaller pieces:

```
if()
{
    // large code block
}
else
{
    // another large code block
}

inline void f()
{
    // large code block
}
inline void g()
{
    // another large code block
}

if()
{
    f();
}
else
{
    g();
}
```

Keep those functions close together in code, at least in source file (you might move the inline functions into the private section of your class to keep the public interface clean, though).

If your source files get very large, it might be a hint that you are packing too many different things into one and the same class. Then think about if you reasonably can export parts of into separate classes that your current class then can aggregate (e. g. low level functions into some kind of driver class, high level functions then using this new driver). This provides the additional benefit that you can reuse the driver in further, different high level implementations.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tips!